# 457 Australian Visa school fees in Queensland

Tags: australia

My husband has been asked to do a 2 year relocation assignment in his company's Brisbane office. He would be going on a 457 (soon to be TSS) visa and we would be bringing our school-aged children with us.

I know that several Australian states charge 457 visa holders fees to send their children to state schools. Does anyone know if Queensland also charges these fees?

If you can point to any information on the internet, that would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Queensland Government content for [Temporary Residents Admissions](https://eqi.com.au/study-options/temporary-residents) includes a datasheet which notes that fees are required for dependents, although there are exemptions (as excerpted below; full details on link, including fee structure).

**[Temporary Residents Admissions Centre Fee Structure & Exemption Criteria](https://eqi.com.au/pdfs/trac-fee-structure-and-exemptions.pdf)**

> **Fees and Payment**
>   Most students holding temporary resident visas are required to pay fees to attend a Queensland state school.
>
> Tuition fees must be paid in advance and are calculated based on the number of weeks of the enrolment (enrolment for part of a week incurs the charge for a full week). Fees are paid whether or not the student actually attends during the period of enrolment.
>
> A Temporary Residents Admission Centre (TRAC) Letter of authority to enrol will be issued after TRAC has received payment for fees.
>
> **Fee exemption**
>   School aged dependants of temporary visa holders may be eligible for an exemption from paying international student school tuition fees in Queensland state schools. For further information please visit [fee exemptions for eligible dependant students of temporary visa holders](http://education.qld.gov.au/schools/school-operations/fee-exemptions.html) on the Department of Education and Training website.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response but I've actually contacted the Queensland education department and was told that residents with a valid 457 visa do not have to pay fees for public school in Queensland. I believe the information you provided applies to international students wanting to study abroad in Queensland. If you have reason to believe that's not the case, I'd really appreciate the clarification :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My kids are currently in Queensland state schools and there are no fees for non-permanent residents :) We do pay activities fees but all students have to pay those. Hope that helps.